# SQL Server : Join on table with no fear of duplicating rows

Tags: sql-server, join, left-join

Let's say I have two tables:

The primary:

**animal_ref**

```
id      name
1       dog
2       cat
3       honey badger
```

And a lookup:

**animal_food**

```
id      animal_id      name
1       1              dog food
2       2              cat food
3       2              fish      
4       2              mice
5       3              larva (ew, gross)
```

Now say I want to join and get the animal's favorite food:

```
SELECT id,
       name
  FROM animal_ref ar
  LEFT OUTER JOIN animal_food af on af.animal_id = ar.id
```

Now, bad example above, but say each animal was supposed to only like one kind of food, however the food table was sloppy and sometimes had the chance of duplicates (because cats are so picky).

Now suppose the world would end if the animal table ended up with a duplicate from this query - we don't really care about what they eat *too* much so if there is a duplicate, we don't mind picking the top one.

How do I make, make, make *sure* despite data flubs that the animal table will always only return its own rows?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you really don't care what you get

```
SELECT id, name
FROM animal_ref ar
LEFT OUTER JOIN (
  SELECT animal_id, MAX(name) AS Name
  FROM animal_food 
  GROUP BY animal_id
  )  af 
ON af.animal_id = ar.id
```

`Cat` will get `mice` btw

Comment: Well, I consider it appropriate that each animal gets their stereotypical food item, so that works out great!

Comment: This will work for me, until I can slap some people around and get TGH's good practice recommendation into use. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The best way to prevent this is to put a unique constraint on the animal_id column. That way you ensure that any particular animal can only exist once in the entire table.

I don't recommend just picking an arbitrary record. It's better to prevent this from happening.

Comment: Good idea. I haven't really ever used unique constraints on any columns other than a primary key. I guess it will just middle-finger sloppy update/insert queries until I fix them?

Answer (score 0):

Please Try it, I hope it is useful to you

```
WITH CTE AS
(
 SELECT *,RN=ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
     PARTITION BY animal_id 
     ORDER BY animal_id DESC) 
     FROM #animal_food 
)

SELECT ar.id, ct.name 
FROM CTE ct 
RIGHT JOIN #animal_ref ar 
   ON ct.animal_id = ar.id 
WHERE RN = 1 OR RN is null
```

Please Change #animal_food to animal_food and #animal_ref to animal_ref

Comment: How did #animal_food and #animal_ref get loaded?

Comment: Dear it is temporary table name  , it's make for shorttime and  not use ahead

Answer (score 0):

I don't agree with the query you mark as correct.

Arif query is ok.

Secondly there must be some way to find frequently use/ordered animal food by particular animal (another table).Does this make any sense ?

BTW.how can you put unique constraint on the animal_id column ?
Cat may like mice,fish,milk etc.